# How to save dictionary or array like String data when in Core data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, core-data

**Goal:**

> Store the uid's of users that have been followed, in core data

**How can I store these uid's given my use case?**

*UIDS = Strings*

Ideas:

- create an array or dict
- create a new attribute for each uid

Comment: You already got the same topic dismissed some 12 hours ago.  Why are you repeating it?

Comment: @ElTomato nuance is always useful my friend. It was dismissed due to lack of focus. I removed it and repost correcting the mistake. (reason for closed)

Comment: Your topic doesn't make sense.  The title first suggests that you want to save a directory.  You are then talking about saving UIDs.  So what you are saving?

Comment: @ElTomato dict or arr. Many ways to save such data. Whichever makes most sense. Maybe this is a little more ambiguity than optimal. But certainly not enough to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to store an array of some values (uids) in device's memory. From my view there are several easy workarounds here.

1. If you are not going to store a massive array of data, you can try a chance with `UserDefaults`. Then your code will look something like this:

```swift
let array = ["array", "of", "some", "values"]

// Write to User Defaults
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(array, forKey: "followedIds")

// Read from it
let readArray = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "followedIds") as! [String]
```

2. If you're going to store a lot of values then it makes sense to use core data. You can store your values as a `String` or `Data`.

In first case you can transform your array into a `String` like so:

```swift
let array = ["array", "of", "some", "values"]

// Specify any separator
let separator = "%^&"

// Join an array into string with the specified separator
let string = array.joined(separator: separator)

// Store it in core data

// Split it later
let readArray = string.split(separator: separator)
```

In second case you can encode it in a JSON representation and use it later:

```swift
let array = ["array", "of", "some", "values"]

// Encode array into Data
var data: Data
do {
    data = try JSONEncoder().encode(data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// Store it in core data

// Decode it later
var readArray: [String]
do {
    readArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I am considering "a lot" to be hundreds of strings, thus going with opt 2

Comment: I guess its `JSONEndoder().encode(array)` @grigorevp